# Trying to work out how to produce a synthetic data set using python or javascript in a repeatable way

Tags: python, node.js, statistics, data-science

I have a reasonably technical background and have done a fair bit of node development, but I’m a bit of a novice when it comes to statistics and a complete novice with python, so any advice on a synthetic data generation experiment I’m trying my hand at would be very welcome :)

I’ve set myself the problem of generating some realistic(ish) sales data for a bricks and mortar store (old school, I know).

I’ve got a smallish real-world transactional dataset (~500k rows) from the internet that I was planning on analysing with a tool of some sort, to provide the input to a PRNG.

Hopefully if I explain my thinking across a couple of broad problem domains, someone(s?!) can help me:

PROBLEM 1
I think I should be able to use the real data I have to either:

a) generate a probability distribution curve or
b) identify an ‘out of the box’ distribution that’s the closest match to the actual data

I’m assuming there’s a tool or library in Python or Node that will do one or both of those things if fed the data and, further, give me the right values to plug in to a PRNG to produce a series of data points that not are not only distributed like the original's, but also within the same sort of ranges.

I suspect b) would be less expensive computationally and, also, better supported by tools - my need for absolute ‘realness’ here isn’t that high - it’s only an experiment :)

Which leads me to…

QUESTION 1: What tools could I use to do do the analysis and generate the data points? As I said, my maths is ok, but my statistics isn't great (and the docs for the tools I’ve seen are a little dense and, to me at least, somewhat impenetrable), so some guidance on using the tool would also be welcome :)

And then there’s my next, I think more fundamental, problem, which I’m not even sure how to approach…

PROBLEM 2
While I *think* the approach above will work well for generating timestamps for each row, I’m going round in circles a little bit on how to model what the transaction is actually for.

I’d like each transaction to be relatable to a specific product from a list of products.

Now the products don’t need to be ‘real’ (I reckon I can just use something like Faker to generate random words for the brand, product name etc), but ideally the distribution of what is being purchased should be a bit real-ey (if that’s a word).

My first thought was just to do the same analysis for price as I’m doing for timestamp and then ‘make up’ a product for each price that’s generated, but I discarded that for a couple of reasons: It might be consistent ‘within’ a produced dataset, but not ‘across’ data sets. And I imagine on largish sets would double count quite a bit.

So my next thought was I would create some sort of lookup table with a set of pre-defined products that persists across generation jobs, but Im struggling with two aspects of that:

1. I’d need to generate the list itself. I would imagine I could filter the original dataset to unique products (it has stock codes) and then use the spread of unit costs in that list to do the same thing as I would have done with the timestamp (i.e. generate a set of products that have a similar spread of unit cost to the original data and then Faker the rest of the data).

QUESTION 2: Is that a sensible approach? Is there something smarter I could do?

2. When generating the transactions, I would also need some way to work out what product to select. I thought maybe I could generate some sort of bucketed histogram to work out what the frequency of purchases was within a range of costs (say $0-1, 1-2$ etc). I could then use that frequency to define the probability that a given transaction's cost would fall within one those ranges, and then randomly select a product whose cost falls within that range...

QUESTION 3: Again, is that a sensible approach? Is there a way I could do that lookup with a reasonably easy to understand tool (or at least one that’s documented in plain English :))

This is all quite high level I know, but any help anyone could give me would be greatly appreciated as I’ve hit a wall with this.

Thanks in advance :)

The synthesised dataset would simply have timestamp, product_id and item_cost columns.

The source dataset looks like this:

```
InvoiceNo,StockCode,Description,Quantity,InvoiceDate,UnitPrice,CustomerID,Country
536365,85123A,WHITE HANGING HEART T-LIGHT HOLDER,6,12/1/2010 8:26,2.55,17850,United Kingdom
536365,71053,WHITE METAL LANTERN,6,12/1/2010 8:26,3.39,17850,United Kingdom
536365,84406B,CREAM CUPID HEARTS COAT HANGER,8,12/1/2010 8:26,2.75,17850,United Kingdom
536365,84029G,KNITTED UNION FLAG HOT WATER BOTTLE,6,12/1/2010 8:26,3.39,17850,United Kingdom
536365,84029E,RED WOOLLY HOTTIE WHITE HEART.,6,12/1/2010 8:26,3.39,17850,United Kingdom
536365,22752,SET 7 BABUSHKA NESTING BOXES,2,12/1/2010 8:26,7.65,17850,United Kingdom
536365,21730,GLASS STAR FROSTED T-LIGHT HOLDER,6,12/1/2010 8:26,4.25,17850,United Kingdom
536366,22633,HAND WARMER UNION JACK,6,12/1/2010 8:28,1.85,17850,United Kingdom
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question might be a little easier to understand if you showed a few rows of your transactional dataset.  And, a question: have you considered randomly perturbing the values in that dataset rather than generating a completely synthetic dataset with similar descriptive statistics? It might be a quicker way to get where you're going.

Comment: Thank your for your response! I've edited the question with some more info on the datasets... Regarding peturbation, I'd not considered that, no. In fact, I'd never even heard of it - am I right in thinking what you're suggesting is to, effectively, add noise to the existing values to generate something very similar (and close-enough for my purposes), but *a bit* different so I could do it over and over again with slightly different outputs?

Comment: Yes, my suggestion is to add or subtract small random values from values in your existing sample  dataset. And, by the way, we *greatly* prefer sample data to be shown in text form rather than images. Indent it by four spaces and it will be shown exactly as you formatted it.

Comment: Ah. I think I see why it's rubbish as an inserted image. Not so easy to review an attachment. I assume doing it as a code snippet is ok? I can't see a tabular data option in the editor...

Comment: Peturbation is a great suggestion! Pretty much bang on to solve the time-series problem, I think - perfect :) Although (and doubtless this is my fault from not being clear enough), as I want each run to have a different subset of products from the same pool of products, but similarly priced to the source data to maintain some semblance to a 'real' price distribution, I'd have a problem there, unless I've misunderstood? The values wouldn't be constrained to 'one-of-these' options across runs of the generation, would they?

Comment: In the end, I used bucketed time and price distributions (histogram) from my original data set to generate the transactions. For price, I used the bucket to randomly choose a product within the price range and for timestamp, same, but randomly chose a minute/second combo from the hour.

Comment: Cool.  I respectfully suggest you write this up as an answer to your own question, so others can benefit.